# CSS Files Hosted in SP Assets Lib Do Not Render Properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, css, intranet, asset-library

So, I'm really hoping someone can help me with this because it's driving me nuts. We have CSS in an Assets Library in SharePoint Online, but when I link to it from our Intranet (not inside SharePoint), the page gets mangled. If I enter the CSS directly into the page -OR- use a developer CDN link -OR- a raw link from bitbucket or github, the pages render correctly. I'm guessing someone here has faced this same issue; what is causing the issue? And how can it be corrected?

Thanks a ton in advance!